# errors when trying to open a virtual env

Tags: python, virtualenv

Trying to follow what I understand to be best practices, I installed virtualenv to be able to install a python module locally (and not break any other programs or dependencies).  Unfortunately, when I try to open a new virtual environment (in bash, in OSX), I see the following error:

```
   $ virtualenv venv
Overwriting /Users/danwalsh/Desktop/naomi/venv/lib/python2.7/site.py with new content
New python executable in /Users/danwalsh/Desktop/naomi/venv/bin/python
copying /Users/danwalsh/anaconda/bin/python => /Users/danwalsh/Desktop/naomi/venv/bin/python
copying /Users/danwalsh/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.dylib => /Users/danwalsh/Desktop/naomi/venv/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
Overwriting /Users/danwalsh/Desktop/naomi/venv/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.py with new content
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /Users/danwalsh/Desktop/naomi/venv/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in <module>
  File "/Users/danwalsh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 581, in get_data
    mod = sys.modules.get(package) or loader.load_module(package)
  File "/Users/danwalsh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 94, in <module>
  File "/Users/danwalsh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "/Users/danwalsh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/Users/danwalsh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "/Users/danwalsh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/Users/danwalsh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/Users/danwalsh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "/Users/danwalsh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/download.py", line 15, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name requests

----------------------------------------

...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danwalsh/anaconda/bin/virtualenv", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(virtualenv.main())
  File "/Users/danwalsh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Users/danwalsh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/Users/danwalsh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/Users/danwalsh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/danwalsh/Desktop/naomi/venv/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

I've googled the error but none of the solutions seem applicable to this situation.  Where might be a good place to go from here?

Comment: since you re using anaconda, y, ` not use method to create virtual enviroment using anacomda only ?

Comment: Thank you, prashant rana, your question pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, here's how I got past this error:

As Prashant Rana noted, anaconda is in use on this system.  The solution was to create a virtual environment using anaconda, rather than venv.  In the shell, I ran:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge desired_module_name
```

and then

```
$ conda create -n mypython3 python=3
```

and finally

```
$ source activate mypython3
```